# Why spring beans registered using registerSingleton() are not visible in getBeanDefinitionNames()?

Tags: spring

When Spring bean is registered using `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton()` method, it's not available in `ApplicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()`.

Is it by design? Maybe I can use some other method to get registered beans?

Comment: Because there is no `BeanDefinition` for a singleton registered that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name `getBeanDefinitionNames` implies it will return the names of all `BeanDefinition`s available in the `ApplicationContext`. A `BeanDefinition` is the recipe on how to create a bean.

When using `registerSingleton` to register an arbitrary bean you created outside the scope of the `ApplicationContext` this obviously doesn't have a `BeanDefinition` and hence it will not be available in that list of names.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that you can make bean registered via `registerSingleton` visible via `getBeanDefinitionNames ` if you register its `BeanDefinition` (eg. using `DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition`)

Comment: If you construct the bean yourself there is no `BeanDefinition`.

Answer (score 3):

You can register and destroy your singleton using `DefaultListableBeanFactory`

1. Inject the `ApplicationContext` by `@Autowired` Spring annotation
2. Initialize a `ConfigurableApplicationContext` object

   ```
   ConfigurableApplicationContext configContext = ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
   ```
3. Initialize a `DefaultListableBeanFactory` object by using `configContext`

   ```
   DefaultListableBeanFactory beanRegistry = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) configContext.getBeanFactory();
   ```
4. Use `beanRegistry` instance to handle your Spring beans

   ```
    //Register a singleton bean 
    beanRegistry.registerSingleton(beanName,object);  
    //Destroy a singleton bean from context
    beanRegistry.destroySingleton(beanName);
   ```